# WP: Display post instead of Subcategory, if Category contains only one single post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am still having a problem with this stuff (and yeah it's still my first WP project) ..

I am displaying categories and their description if there is more than one post in that category.
BUT if there is only one post in a category I need to display the link to that post directly.
This works (in parts) with the following code, but only if there is one "1-post-category". If there are multiple it only displays one (the latest added I guess). So there must be something wrong or missing. A loop I guess...? Would be great if one could have a closer look - MANY THANKS!

```
<?php                   
     foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

         // If there is only one post available, go directly to the post
         if($category->count == 1) {
             $all_posts = get_posts($category);
             echo '<div class="card"><div class="card-header"><h4>' . get_the_title($all_posts[0]->ID) . '</h4><div class="card-body">' . wp_trim_words( get_the_content($all_posts[0]->ID), 30, '...') . '</div><div class="card-footer"><a href="' . get_permalink($all_posts[0]->ID) . '" class="readmore">Read more</a></div></div></div>';
                                
          // otherwise display subcategories
          } else {
             echo '<div class="card"><div class="card-header"><h4>' . $category->name . '</h4><div class="card-body">' . wp_trim_words($category->description, 30, '...') . '</div><div class="card-footer"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" class="readmore">Read more</a></div></div></div>';
          }
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your output it's tough to say, but I'm pretty sure that the line:

`$all_posts = get_posts($category)`

Isn't working the way you think. Instead, try this:

`$all_posts = get_posts( array('category'=>$category->term_id) );`

Comment: Thank you @Greg, this works exactly as I had hoped for! I would never ever been ablse to fix that on my own. <3